# AWS EC2 インスタンスタイプを変更した場合の影響について

Tags: aws

EC2のマシンタイプを誤って高額なものでWEBサイトを作ってしまいました。
無料と書いてあったのですが1時間$0.732、月額で固定費だけで6万円ほどかかり、さらに転送量などで倍近い12万円程になりそうです。

しかし転送量は解決しました。CloudFrontを使うと一気に1/1000ほど値段が下がりました。また、CloudFrontの値段は2日で1ドルほどと格安で収まっています。

マシンタイプを変えると、MariaDBやNginxのインストールなど全てのデータはどこに行ってしまうのでしょうか？

◆ストレージは別で保管されていて、マシンタイプだけ変更すれば綺麗に移転できるのでしょうか？

◆EC2インスタンス作成時にIPアドレスが付与されますが、これもVPC（？）で綺麗に維持できますか？

インスタンスを停止すれば済む話ですが、SEO的に悪そうなので止められません。
AWS参考書を買ったのですが、慌ててるので文章がはっきり理解できません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

仮想マシンのインスタンスサイズは任意に変更することができます。このとき仮想マシンの再起動を伴います。ストレージに格納された内容は維持されます。

仮想マシンに標準で割り当てられているIPアドレスは、動的に割り当てられるもので、仮想マシンの再起動により異なるIPアドレスに変更される場合があります。ユーザーが操作しなくともAWS側のメンテナンスの都合で仮想マシンが移動する場合もあり、再起動しなければIPアドレスが維持されるものではありません。

VPCで割り当てたIPアドレスはユーザー用に固定で確保されます。VPCで取得したIPアドレスは仮想マシンのインスタンスサイズを変更するなどしても、変わることはありません。

Comment: 停止してプロパティでことどとく簡単に変更できました。死ぬかと思いました助かりました！